# How can i use HiddenField id as a variable for its value in c#

Tags: c#, hidden-field

I have 1000 hiddenfield. How can i put their value in sql database using for loop. Like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Control hiddenfield = this.FindControl("HiddenField" + i);
        
    String p = Convert.ToString(hiddenfield.Value);
    string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO [" + table_name2 + "] (CT1) VALUES ('" + p + "')");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, Connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change tablename as requred!

```
        string query = "INSERT INTO tablename ( CT1 ) VALUES ( @value )";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        try
        {  
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
            con.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Control hiddenfield = this.FindControl("HiddenField" + i);        
                String p = Convert.ToString(hiddenfield.Value);

                cmd.Parameters["@value"].Value = p;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Show exception as required!
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Dear, your code showing error in my c# code.  `cmd.Parameters["@value"].Value = Convert.ToString(this.FindControl("HiddenField" + i).Value);` here last Value error. Contain dose not contain definition for 'Value".

Comment: Dear that is your code, i just simplified these two line of code, -> Control hiddenfield = this.FindControl("HiddenField" + i);
        
    String p = Convert.ToString(hiddenfield.Value);

Comment: Edited the code debug it

Comment: Try it now!!!!!!

Comment: Finally this code worked for me. Thanks every one. `for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            HiddenField hiddenfield = this.FindControl("HiddenField" + i) as HiddenField;



            string sqlquery = ("INSERT INTO [" + table_name2 + "] (CT1) VALUES ('" + Convert.ToString(hiddenfield.Value) + "')");

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, Connection);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }`